# Apache stops writing logs after moving/deleting them

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, logging, amazon-web-services

I have a bunch of ec2 instances running web services; every hour I want to copy the logs back to S3. Which works perfectly well.

But, it appears if I move the logs and then touch a new file, or just write the contents to 0 Apache stops writing the logs from that point.

How is it best to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log files are accessed through their file descriptor (inode), not their name.

To rotate apache logs safely you must re-create the log file and then restart apache.

Most distros come with apache logrotate settings preconfigured; take a look at those.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, the logrotate scripts issue a `reload` (send `SIGHUP`) to the running process after doing the logrotation and creating a new log file. This enables the running process (apache in your case) to reopen the log file and continue to write logs to the right file descriptor.

Comment: The standard apache logrotate scripts run differently, because apache includes a restart command that does not close any connections.